# How can I add a text and a bakground-image in a card?

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I tried to make a text over a picture in a card. I need a picture in the background and a text in the foreground. When I click on it, it should change to another screen, but I haven´t coded it so far. This is the code where i tried to make a text "over" the picture, but I get an error. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

```
Card(
              semanticContainer: true,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/Bild1.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
                Text("test")
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `Stack` to position the Text above the image; you cannot just add the Text without any context beneath the Card's `child`. Try this code:

```dart
Card(
  semanticContainer: true,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Image.asset(
        'images/Bild1.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      Text("test"),
    ],
  ),
);
```